# Syntax highlighting in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a syntax highlighter tool that enables you to highlight  **selected** code in a `textarea`, and to select the programming language. 
I would like to select code, then choose the language (java or ruby..).

I tried the ckeditor syntax highlighter plugin but didn't like it.

Comment: This http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ is used by Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/examples/ManageReferral.java).

Answer (score 2):

[Ace](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) and [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) are two of the most popular, used in browsers dev tools (Firefox/Webkit) and GitHub Gists, etc.

Comment: but they don't give u and UI to selected the wanred programmng lagage.do they?

Comment: Probably not, but you might be able to hack around that. Weird use-case, are you sure that's the best route to go?

Answer (score 1):

There are most popular syntak highlighting tool:

EditArea, CodePress and CodeMirror